# Output quater-imaginary base numbers in binary

Tags: code-golf, complex-numbers

Write a function or program that outputs [Quater-imaginary base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base) displayed as binary digits. The number base is 2*i*, where *i* is the square root of -1. See [Complex Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) for more details on *i*. Each digit position can go from 0 to 3 (quaternary), as each real and imaginary part is -4 times as large as the previous real and imaginary part. The quaternary digits in binary are as follows: `0: 00`, `1: 01`, `2: 10` & `3: 11`.

Breakdown of digit positions:

```
re   im       16 -8i  -4  2i   1 -0.5i, etc.
 4    0        1   0   3   0   0        (quaternary representation)
              01  00  11  00  00        (binary representation)
```

The number `100110000` is 1x16 + 3x-4 = 16 + -12 = 4.

```
re   im       16 -8i  -4  2i   1 -0.5i, etc.
 0    5        0   0   0   3   0   2    (quaternary representation)
              00  00  00  11  00 .10    (binary representation)
```

The number `1100.1` is 3x2*i* + 2x-0.5*i* = 6*i* + -*i* = 5*i*.

Your code will take a pair of numbers, which could be integer or floating point, and will output the complex number as a string of binary digits. The first number will be real, the second input number will be the imaginary value. A binary point must only be printed if there are non-zero number positions below 1 (i.e. if any of the positions for -0.5*i*, -0.25, 0.125*i*, etc. have a non-zero digit). Leading and trailing zeros are not allowed, except for a single zero digit immediately before the binary point if there are no other digits. The output must not start with a binary point (*`00.1` - wrong, `0.1` - right, *`.1` - wrong, *`0.10` - wrong). You may assume that all input numbers will have finite binary representations.

Test numbers:

```
re   im            output
 0    0                 0
 1    0                 1
 2    0                10
 3    0                11
 4    0         100110000
-1    0             10011
-2    0             10010
-3    0             10001
 0    1               100.1
 0    2               100
 0    3              1000.1
 0    4              1000
 0   -1                 0.1
 0   -2           1001100
 0   -3           1001100.1
 3    4              1011
 4    3         100111000.1
 6   -9         101110010.1
-6    9       10011100110.1
-9   -6           1110111
 0.5 14.125   10011001101.001001
```

Note: The output of all integer values will end in `.1` if the imaginary part is odd.

Standard code-golf.

Comment: This is a good challenge, but the explanation could be a whole lot clearer. You should clarify the process: it goes from complex numbers, to an interleaved *quaternary* representation, to a *binary* representation mapping `0 → 00, 1 → 01, 2 → 10, 3 → 11`.

Comment: @Mauris I've made a whole bunch of edits to address your comment. Let me know if I can improve it further.

Comment: What if it is recurring in binary?

Comment: @LeakyNun It says right in the challenge: "You may assume that all input numbers will have finite binary representations."

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 340 bytes

```
f=x=>[0,...x.toString(16)].reverse().map(d=>s=d<'.'?s:d<`0`?d+s.slice(0,-1):`${(c=+`0x${d}`+(c>>4)+m^m)>>2&3}${c&3}`+s,c=s='.',m=x<0?3:12)&&s
g=(s,t,n=s.indexOf`.`,m=t.indexOf`.`)=>n<m?g(0+s,t):n>m?g(s,0+t):t[s.length]?g(s+0,t):s.replace(/\d/g,(c,i)=>`${t[i]>>1}${t[i]&1}${c>>1}${c&1}`).replace(/^0+(\d)|\.?0*$/g,'$1')
(r,i)=>g(f(r),f(i/2))
```

`f` converts a number into base `-4` (with trailing `.` if the number is an integer). `g` takes two base `-4` numbers, pads them at both ends to the same length and `.` position, shuffles the digits together, converts everything from base `4` to base `2`, then finally strips leading and trailing zeros.

Explanation: To represent the given complex number in modified-base `2i` we need to represent the real part and half of the complex part (i.e. dividing the imaginary part by `2i`) in base `2i²` (i.e. `-4`), shuffle the digits together, and then convert them from base `4` to base `2`. To represent a real number in base `-4` we start with the base `4` conversion. Alternate digits have the correct sign (in the case of a positive number, these are the digits in the even positions; in the case of a negative number, these are the digits in the odd positions) but the remaining digits have the wrong sign and a correction needs to be applied. Examples:

```
 0 -> 000 -> 000 (no correction needed)
 4 -> 010 -> 130 }
 8 -> 020 -> 120 } (correction includes carry)
12 -> 030 -> 110 }
```

As you can see, the correction is `8` minus the original digit, mod `8`. However a slightly more convenient calculation is the original digit, plus 3, xor 3 (indeed in 32-bit integer arithmetic we could simply write `+0xCCCCCCCC^0xCCCCCCCC` to convert the entire number in one go). Finally as the correction applies to alternate digits it is simpler to do an initial conversion to base `16` which automatically picks up pairs of base `4` digits, then correct using a factor of either `3` or `0xC` as appropriate. It just remains to ignore the `-` sign.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 313 bytes

Since no-one has posted an answer yet I thought I'd kick it off myself.

```
$r=$ARGV[0];$i=$ARGV[1]/2;$m=1;while($r!=int($r)||$i!=int($i)){$c++;$m*=-1;$i*=4;$r*=4}while($r||$i){$r-=($d[$n++]=$r/$m%4)*$m;$i-=($d[$n++]=$i/$m%4)*$m;$m*=-4}$_=join("",map({sprintf"%02b",$_}reverse splice(@d,$c*2)))||"0";@d and$_.=".".join("",map({sprintf"%02b",$_}reverse@d));s/^0+1/1/;s/(\.\d*1)0+$/$1/;print
```

I'm sure there are lots of opportunities to golf this further.